# Change background-image after specified time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript, so apologies that I haven't even attempted this as I have no clue how to even begin.

I have 3 images. Image1 is a png file, and Image2 and Image 3 are animated gifs.

What I need is very specific however. I would like Image1 to change to Image 2 after x seconds, and then change to Image3 after y seconds. Once Image3 is loaded I would like that gif to remain as the page background.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Okay so this is what I have at the moment,

```
var delay1 = 104000;
var delay2 = 14000;
setBackground('Image1.png');
setTimeout(function() {
setBackground('Image2.gif');
setTimeout(function() {
setBackground('Image3.gif');
}, delay2);
}, delay1);

function setBackground(src) {
image.style.backgroundImage = 'url('Image1.png + Image2.gif + Image3.gif')';
}
```

When run, no background image loads at all. Sorry if i'm being a complete moron. Like I said, i'm new to javascript...

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: it should be cyclic??

Comment: Nope, I want the first image to load with the page. Then change to a gif after say 1 second, and change the last gif after say 2 seconds, and I want the last gif to remain as the page background

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `setTimeout` function. It accepts two arguments: function and delay (ms), function will be called after delay.

```
var delay1 = 2000; // 2 seconds
var delay2 = 3000; // 3 seconds
setBackground('image-1.png');
setTimeout(function() {
    setBackground('image-2.gif');
    setTimeout(function() {
        setBackground('image-3.gif');
    }, delay2);
}, delay1);

function setBackground(src) {
    image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src + ')';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what sources am I supposed to be entering in the last bit of code?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: The last part. function setBackground... I have no idea what to do from that point. Also, how would it be possible to style the background images? e.g positioning etc. If it would be easier, and you don't mind, could i get an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: src is path to your images, just change 'image-1.png' etc. to desired path. checkout all style.background* properties for positioning etc..